# Strange issue with Registry.GetValue()

Tags: c#, registry, dynamics-crm-2011

I have used the following code to read "UserName" and "Password" from registry:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\MSCRM");

string username = key.GetValue("UserName").ToString();
string password = key.GetValue("Password").ToString();

key.Close();
```

However, it appears that sometimes `GetValue()` returns null that means "UserName" and "Password" keys do not exist. I have looked in windows registry but actually keys are there. The strange thing is that it happens from time to time.

Any ideas?

Comment: For access to `LocalMachine` you must run the application run as admin mode! If you want to save an read without run as admin, you can use from `CurrentUser` to access to registry easily.

Comment: I have checked and the application is running in an administrator's context. So it has access to the subkey and sometimes almost to the required values but, what is strange, not always.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that you sometimes run the application in 32 or 64 bits. Make sure the keys exists both under

```
"Software\Microsoft\MSCRM"
```

and

```
"Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSCRM"
```

If your application run as 32bits (x86 build) it will look in that area of the registry instead.

Comment: I have checked the target platform of solution and it is set to "Any CPU". Also the application is executed on 64-bit machine. So if I am not wrong, the application always run in 64-bit. Nevertheless, I have not found "Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSCRM" node in registry.